# Java threads and HTTP requests deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, network-programming, threadpool

I encounter a problem with java threads and I am not sure if its related to my approach or if thread pooling is going to resolve what I am trying to achieve.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            verifier[i]=new Thread();
            verifier[i].start();
        }
```

I initialize 100 threads and start them. In the threads the code that gets executed is just

```
        con = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection(url);
        // gets only the header
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        con.setConnectTimeout(2000); // set timeout to 2 seconds
```

These threads repeat the process above over a long list of url/data.

The first 50 threads execute almost instantly then they just stop for 60 seconds or so and then there is another spike of execution that 20 of them or so finish at the same time and so on. The same deadlock occurs even if there is 4 of them.

My first guess was a deadlock. I am not sure how to resolve the issue and maintain a constant execution pace, without deadlocks and stops.

I am looking for an explanation of why this occurs and how it can be resolved.

By DeadLock I reefer to the Java Virtual Machine and how it handles thread. Not deadlock caused by my threads.

SCREENSHOT OF THREAD EXECUTION:

[image]

It looks like the threads are dying for no reason and I don't know why?!

Comment: for deadlocks to occur you'll have to use `synchronized`, `.wait()` or other kinds of `java.util.concurrent` related things. Do you do that somewhere?

Comment: By what you are suggesting I am not sure you understand what I am doing. I am not sharing any resources and I am referring to deadlock caused by Java Virtual Machine thread handling.

Comment: Java's threads don't deadlock just out of nowhere. Two reasons limit them: blocking in software and the limit of computation time your cpu cores provide. If there are no limits in your software you could still hit a limit on the network (as in your bandwidth), within the network implementation or just on CPU load.

Comment: What I am trying to illustrate is that Java's Virtual Machine has an issue with networking packages and cannot predict which thread to execute next which causes what I assume to be a deadlock. Its not a bug, but this is my assumption and thats why I am looking for a better one.

Comment: @zapl I believe I demonstrated with my code above that it would be very hard to hit a bandwidth limit by just requesting headers of 20 websites. I am more interested in the idea that the CPU limits my threads but that would in turn mean that a similar scenario would happen with any other multi-threaded application which it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure it is not server-side problem?

Comment: @Katona I am not requesting the same URL but different urls from a long list of them.

Comment: A total irrational, intuitive tip: try to turn on the parallel GC.

Comment: Your operating system decides when it schedules which thread. No userspace program regarless of programming language can predict when they are being executed. Java works perfectly fine with regards to that. One problem with your code might be that you use too many threads. Trying to execute far more threads in parallel than cores on your CPU will result in worse performance because they have to be constantly switched. But that should not cause such large hiccups. I would suspect something else in your code to cause that. Thats why I asked for synchronized.

Comment: @zapl I am going to try to run more tests and experiments and post here.

Comment: If you add some more code like how the 100 threads get their work and how you make sure that threads don't visit websites that have not been visited by others we could be of more help. Btw is it actually `new Thread()` i.e. no subclass and no `Runnable`? That would mean that you just start threads that do nothing then exit.

Comment: @zapl, because the code was too big to paste, I posted 2 pastebin links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the operating system configurable limit of tcp/ip connections gets hit, which causes the JVM to block waiting for a new TCP/IP connection to be created, which will only happen if a connection already used get's closed.

This could help to find what is going on:

- profile the run with [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) which comes with the JVM itself (run it on the command line with jvisualvm). There should be indication of how many threads are created and why are they blocked, deadlocks, etc.
- Wait for it to block and take thread dumps of the JVM process to check for deadlocks in the thread stack traces using jstack or visualvm, search for the deadlock keyword.
- Check with netstat -nao the state of your TCP connections, to see if the operating system limit is getting hit, if there are many connections in CLOSE_WAIT at the times the blocking occurs
- Are you behind a corporate proxy/firewall, you could be hitting some other sort of security limit that prevents you from opening more TCP connections, not necessarily the limit of the operating system

If none of this helps you can always edit the question with further findinds, but based on the description of the code other limits are getting hit that on a first look don't seem related to JVM thread deadlocks, hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I posted a code above which you can read while I am checking all of the things on ur list.

Comment: I have updated some more info on the description. Threads die after a while during execution.

Comment: The Verifier would not log anything in case of an IOException, the catch block only contains return 0. Fixing the logging and adding some more logging statements should identify why the threads are dying.